# how to use chutzpah in current project

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2012

I am going through setting up chutzpah and Jasmine for unit testing my project in typescript.

I have installed Jasmine using npm but I am quite confused how to include chutzpah in visual studio code.

I went to this GitHub but nothing is clear to me:-

https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah

Also, I downloaded files for visual studio code from below sources:-

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-2795.ChutzpahTestRunnerContextMenuExtension

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-2795.ChutzpahTestAdapterfortheTestExplorer

When I try to load above-downloaded files as an extension in visual code I get the error:-

extension/package.json not found inside zip.

How to include or install chutzpah in my project and then use the chutzpah.json file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The extensions are for VS, not VSCode.

Answer (score 2):

First from command line go to you project location and do:

```
npm init
```

this will create package.json

Than:
chuzpah.json you can create manually and run at first from Visual Studio with right click, if you installed plugin properly, you will see run Unit tests option.
Seting up chutzpah.json is tricky part. 
 [here is template for setup](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Chutzpah.json-Settings-File):

```
{        
"Framework": "qunit|jasmine|mocha",

"FrameworkVersion": "",

"EnableTestFileBatching": "true|false",

"InheritFromParent": "true|false",

"InheritFromPtah": "<Path to another chutzpah.json>",

"IgnoreResourceLoadingErrors": "true|false"

"TestFileTimeout": "<Timeout in milliseconds>",

"TestHarnessLocationMode": "TestFileAdjacent|SettingsFileAdjacent|Custom",

"TestHarnessDirectory": "<Path to a folder>",

"TestHarnessReferenceMode": "Normal|AMD",

"RootReferencePathMode":"DriveRoot|SettingsFileDirectory",

"CodeCoverageIncludes": [],

"CodeCoverageExcludes": [],

"CodeCoverageIgnores": [],

"CodeCoverageExecutionMode": "Manual|Always|Never",

"CodeCoverageSuccessPercentage": <Number from 0 to 100>,

"CodeCoverageTimeout": <Timeout in milliseconds>

"References": [],

"Tests": [],

"CustomTestHarnessPath": "<Path to custom test harness file>",

"Compile": <A compile configuration object>,

"Server": <A server configuration object>,

"TestPattern": "<Regex test name pattern>",

"AMDBaseUrl": "<Path to same location that your Require.js config baseurl points to>",

"AMDAppDirectory": "<The root folder for your AMD paths>",

"UserAgent": "<Custom user agent to use during testing>",

"Transforms": [],

"EnableTracing": true|false,

"TraceFilePath": "<Path to log file. Defaults to %temp%/chutzpah.log>",

"Parallelism": "<Max degree of parallelism for Chutzpah. Defaults to number of CPUs>",

"BrowserArguments": <A map of browser name (keys) to corresponding browser arguments (values), i.e.; { 'chrome': '--allow-file-access-from-files' }.>
}
```

After all, you can use commang line and Chutzpah runner to run you unit test as part of CI